# Can't get DEFAULT Microsoft Template for Association form to work! Reproducible

Tags: workflow, 2013, asp.net

The default association form template is giving an null reference exception. This is happening with a **blank** project and on two PCs with Workflow Foundation installed. I've taken a screenshot of every click I've taken to reproduce the error, and it happens every single time.

Creating a new sharepoint project:
[image]

Creating a farm solution:
[image]
Right clicking on the solution and adding a new workflow:
[image]
Adding a list workflow:
[image]
Reusable:
[image]
Right clicking on the workflow and adding an association form:
[image]
[image]
Creating a new list:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Adding the workflow to the list:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Clicking Next so the association form shows up:
[image]

What I've tried:

- Installed workflow foundation on multiple PCs, created a new project each time with visual studio: same results.
- Found [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/he-IL/083b205a-f151-4641-9868-fbcadf31cbfd/workflow-association-form-for-sharepoint-2013-workflow) indicating a reference problem and attempted to add the reference manually (which had no effect)
- Removed the following line, which allowed the association form to show up, but I am not sure what the repercussions are, because [I can't find this control documented ANYWHERE!](http://www.google.com/search?q=WorkflowAssociationFormContextControl%20msdn)

  WorkflowServices:WorkflowAssociationFormContextControl ID="WorkflowAssociationFormContextControl1" runat="server"

  [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPChunkedStringBuffer.Append(String str) + 0 Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WorkflowAssociationFormContextControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was that we had SharePoint 2013 RTM installed. After we installed this update: ubersrvsp2013-kb2767999-fullfile-x64-glb.exe it fixed the problem.